# How to execute multiple programs in Makefile

Tags: makefile

Here is part of my Makefile:

```
FLAGS = -Wall -Werror -std=c99
DEPENDENCIES = p.h

test: s d
    @./s < input.dat > output.txt
    @./d < output.txt

s: s.o helper.o
    gcc -Wall -o $@ $^

d: d.o helper.o
    gcc -Wall -o $@ $^

%.o: %.c ${DEPENDENCIES}
    gcc -Wall -c $<
```

Why is error 1 showing up whenever I call "make test". Is this the proper way of compiling two programs and then executing it through Makefile?

The output:

```
cc    -c -o s.o s.c
cc    -c -o helper.o helper.c
gcc -Wall -Werror -std=c99 -o s s.o helper.o
cc    -c -o d.o d.c
gcc -Wall -Werror -std=c99 -o d d.o helper.o
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

Comment: What happens when you run those commands yourself, without using `make` at all? That is, does `gcc -Wall -o d d.o` succeed? If not, how does it fail?

Comment: Hmm. Clearly the `%.o: %.c` rule isn't matching, since you're getting the default rule (which uses `cc`) instead. Probably not the immediate issue, though, since gcc should generally be happy to link any valid object file, no matter which compiler built it.

Comment: Do you have any idea what might be the issue?

Comment: It's probably one of your executables, which returns the error.

Comment: Yup. If you took out the `@`s (which are hiding output), you should see what that error is.